# Configserver ModSecurity: How to block an ip IF it hits a certain url more than N times?

Tags: mod-security, configserver

We have the problem of hackers trying to submit forged payment requests. They return the url /checkout?fail=1 when their attempts fails.

Using modsec, How can we block their ip IF they visit that url more than 3 times?

Comment: I don't know with modsec (google?) but it's easy to do with fail2ban

Comment: thanks, but I can't even see in their docs how to do this.

Comment: You can look https://serverfault.com/questions/416926/automatically-block-ip-who-requests-certain-url or on Google, there are a lot of examples/solutions how to do that

Comment: Thank you.  Believe it or not, I searched high and low before posting this.